# Why won't newly installed Django app with NGINX serve static assets properly?

Tags: django, macos, nginx, gunicorn

I have a Mac running OS X 10.9.3. I am trying to setup a Django application backed by a PostgreSQL database served by gunicorn, with static assets served by NGINX. I'm an old hand at Django with MySQL running with the developement server (`manage.py runserver`). But I'm new to setting it up with virtualenv, gunicorn and NGINX. So I'm following the instructions [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn).

My Django Project is being served successfully at localhost:3026. As a test of the database connectivity, I wanted to take a look at the Django Admin interface. I visited localhost:3026/admin/
I have included a screenshot below.

Why does this admin page look so ugly? It lacks the neccessary graphical interface and css that it is supposed to have? It looks like NGINX is not properly serving up those static assets. How can I troubleshoot and fix this issue?

**EDIT**:

After I posted this question, I did `python manage.py collectstatic`. That went and successfully copied all the static files to where they were supposed to (I think?) live in `/opt/myenv/static`. You can see the output of that command [**here**](https://gist.github.com/syedsaqibali/77877df8941af96f0711). I then re-started gunicorn and nginx. I thought that would fix it. But unfortunately it didn't. The issue remains. In my Django settings.py file, I have configured the STATIC variables as follows:

```
STATIC_ROOT = "/opt/myenv/static/"
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why won't newly installed Django app with NGINX serve static assets?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24879292/why-wont-newly-installed-django-app-with-nginx-serve-static-assets)

Answer (score 1):

Try run command,

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

If the commands executes successfuly, the static file would be generated in your project path, and then if you config the right static path, the web page will be correct.

Comment: Thanks, I did that. And it went and collected all the static files and successfully deposited them into my static directory `/opt/myenv/static/`. See: https://gist.github.com/syedsaqibali/77877df8941af96f0711. I thought it would fix the problem. But still the admin screen is ugly and those static assets don't seem to be being served.